# Getting error " No provider for AlertIconAndTypesService!"

Tags: angular, vmware-clarity

I am using clarity module with my angular 4 code. 
When using their [alert box](https://vmware.github.io/clarity/documentation/alerts#examples) example, I am getting the above error

Example Code

```
<div class="alert alert-info">
    <div class="alert-items">
        <div class="alert-item">
            <div class="alert-icon-wrapper">
                <clr-icon class="alert-icon" shape="info-circle"></clr-icon>
            </div>
            <span class="alert-text">...</span>
            <div class="alert-actions">
                <a href="..." class="alert-action">Acknowledge</a>
                <a href="..." class="alert-action">Reset to green</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close">
        <clr-icon aria-hidden="true" shape="close"></clr-icon>
    </button>
</div>
```

Error stack details

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: No provider for
>   AlertIconAndTypesService! Error: No provider for
>   AlertIconAndTypesService!
>       at injectionError (core.es5.js:1169)
>       at noProviderError (core.es5.js:1207)
>       at ReflectiveInjector_.webpackJsonp.../../../core/@angular/core.es5.js.ReflectiveInjector_.*throwOrNull
>   (core.es5.js:2649)
>       at ReflectiveInjector*.webpackJsonp.../../../core/@angular/core.es5.js.ReflectiveInjector_.*getByKeyDefault
>   (core.es5.js:2688)
>       at ReflectiveInjector*.webpackJsonp.../../../core/@angular/core.es5.js.ReflectiveInjector_.*getByKey
>   (core.es5.js:2620)
>       at ReflectiveInjector*.webpackJsonp.../../../core/@angular/core.es5.js.ReflectiveInjector_.get
>   (core.es5.js:2489)
>       at resolveNgModuleDep (core.es5.js:9475)
>       at NgModuleRef_.webpackJsonp.../../../core/@angular/core.es5.js.NgModuleRef_.get
>   (core.es5.js:10557)
>       at resolveDep (core.es5.js:11060)
>       at createClass (core.es5.js:10913)
>       at injectionError (core.es5.js:1169)
>       at noProviderError (core.es5.js:1207)
>       at ReflectiveInjector_.webpackJsonp.../../../core/@angular/core.es5.js.ReflectiveInjector_.*throwOrNull
>   (core.es5.js:2649)
>       at ReflectiveInjector*.webpackJsonp.../../../core/@angular/core.es5.js.ReflectiveInjector_.*getByKeyDefault
>   (core.es5.js:2688)
>       at ReflectiveInjector*.webpackJsonp.../../../core/@angular/core.es5.js.ReflectiveInjector_.*getByKey
>   (core.es5.js:2620)
>       at ReflectiveInjector*.webpackJsonp.../../../core/@angular/core.es5.js.ReflectiveInjector_.get
>   (core.es5.js:2489)
>       at resolveNgModuleDep (core.es5.js:9475)
>       at NgModuleRef_.webpackJsonp.../../../core/@angular/core.es5.js.NgModuleRef_.get
>   (core.es5.js:10557)
>       at resolveDep (core.es5.js:11060)
>       at createClass (core.es5.js:10913)
>       at resolvePromise (polyfills.bundle.js:3328)
>       at resolvePromise (polyfills.bundle.js:3299)
>       at polyfills.bundle.js:3376
>       at ZoneDelegate.webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask
>   (polyfills.bundle.js:2969)
>       at Object.onInvokeTask (core.es5.js:3881)
>       at ZoneDelegate.webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask
>   (polyfills.bundle.js:2968)
>       at Zone.webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask (polyfills.bundle.js:2736)
>       at drainMicroTaskQueue (polyfills.bundle.js:3140)
>       at

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error suggests, import the `AlertIconAndTypesService` service in your module

So in your `app.module.ts` file

```
import { AlertIconAndTypesService } from "clarity-angular/emphasis/alert/providers/icon-and-types-service";

....
@NgModule({
...
providers:['AlertIconAndTypesService']
...
})
```

Comment: But it is not mentioned in their documentation

Comment: Dont know much about docs, but the error is pretty self explanatory. You can just type AlertIconAndTypesService in the providers array, and visual code editor will import it from proper path :-)

Comment: After importing it, the error got resolved. Thanks for explanation though.

Comment: I've confirmed the class exists, but I'm still getting Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'clarity-angular/emphasis/alert/providers/icon-and-types-service' in my ng serve command.

Comment: You have installed the npm module for clarity icons.. ‘npm install clarity-icons —save’ ?

Answer (score 6):

The issue is actually described in the big red box under the "Code & Examples" header in [the alerts documentation on the Clarity website](https://vmware.github.io/clarity/documentation/alerts).

So you need to do one of two things:

1: Turn your alert into a `clr-alert` component.

```
<clr-alert>
    <!-- "info" is the default -->
    <div clr-alert-item class="alert-item">
        <!-- clr-alert-item is optional at this time; maybe not later... -->
        <!-- note that the .alert-items wrapper is not need with clr-alert -->
        <div class="alert-icon-wrapper">
            <clr-icon class="alert-icon" shape="info-circle"></clr-icon>
        </div>
        <span class="alert-text">...</span>
        <div class="alert-actions">
            <a href="..." class="alert-action">Acknowledge</a>
            <a href="..." class="alert-action">Reset to green</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- the close button is also included in the component -->
</clr-alert>
```

2: Use the `.static` classname to have the AlertComponent ignore your straight HTML alert.

```
<div class="alert alert-info">
    <div class="alert-items">
        <div class="alert-item static">
            <!-- .static hides the alert-item from the Angular component lookup -->
            <div class="alert-icon-wrapper">
                <clr-icon class="alert-icon" shape="info-circle"></clr-icon>
            </div>
            <span class="alert-text">...</span>
            <div class="alert-actions">
                <a href="..." class="alert-action">Acknowledge</a>
                <a href="..." class="alert-action">Reset to green</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close">
        <clr-icon aria-hidden="true" shape="close"></clr-icon>
    </button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have added **`AlertIconAndTypesService`** under provides inside app.module.ts

```
import { AlertIconAndTypesService } from 'clarity-angular/emphasis/alert/providers/icon-and-types-service';
```

and then,

```
@NgModule({
 providers: [
       AlertIconAndTypesService
    ]
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Import in app.module.ts file:

import { DeviceDetectorService } from 'ngx-device-detector';

And add in providers array

providers: [
DeviceDetectorService
]